# Download with smartphone generate xls file with PHPExcel

Tags: php, header, xls

I have a big problem when I want to download on my smart phone a xls file generated by PHPExcel it me download a php file named my page, while on my pc it load properly.

> ```
> header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
> header('Content-Disposition:inline;filename=fichie.xls');
> $writer->save('php://output');
> exit();
> ```

Comment: add teste with header('Content-Disposition:attachement;filename=fichie.xls'); don't works

Comment: maybe the content-disposition header should be attachment: 

`header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fichie.xls"');`

Answer (score 1):

There's two problems with your line that sets the content disposition.

1. It should have spaces between the words, which is a standard requirement for headers.
2. It should be `attachment` if you want the file to download, as opposed to display inline.

e.g.

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=fichie.xls');
```